# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in react

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using ReactJs and putting map inside map but getting this error in line where I am using map function in c.children

{c.description} is working fine. But I am not able to map c.children.

JSON:

Reference: http://prntscr.com/l68aqt

apiData: http://prntscr.com/l68dyk

Code:

```
<div className="side-tab">
              { apiData !== false &&
              apiData.data.map(((c) => (<div>
                {c.description}
                {
                  c.childrens.map(i => (
                    <ProductTab />
                  ))
                }
              </div>)
              ))
              }
            </div>
```

Comment: Let's first make sure you follow these steps, First you make the request in the `componentDidMount` and then you setState with new data. Right? If so can we still see your componentDidMount function?

Comment: to make sure, you can check this with this condition :
(!!apiData && !!apiData.data). Should work

Comment: In apiData I am getting this Json data http://prntscr.com/l68dyk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
  <div className="side-tab">
    {apiData && apiData.data && apiData.data.map(c => (
        <div>
          {c.description}
          {c.childrens && c.childrens.map(i => (
            <ProductTab />
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
  </div>
```

Comment: Getting same error TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the `map` function in an undefined property. This means that `c.childrens` is undefined. If you see your data, some items in `apiData` have the property `childrens` while others don't ("Training and certification" and "Tools" don't have it). The solution is to check if they are not undefined before calling the map function.

Check if c.childrens is not undefined, or if it has values:

```
c.childrens && c.childrens.map
```

or

```
c.childrens && c.childrens.length > 0 && c.childrens.map
```

So your code will look like this:

```
<div className="side-tab">
    {apiData !== false &&
        apiData.data.map(((c) => (<div>
            {c.description}
            {
             c.childrens && c.childrens.length > 0 && c.childrens.map(i => (
                <ProductTab />
              ))
            }
          </div>)
          ))
          }
        </div>
```